# Randomly pick one testimonial post

Tags: wp-query

I want to show one randomly picked testimonial on a page.

Each testimonial is a post with a category of 'quote'.

Each post has a custom field named 'who' with a name.

I'm trying to use this code.

```
<div id="introBottom" class="group">
      <?php
      $quote_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category' => 'quote',
                'orderby' => 'rand',
                'showposts' => 1
            );

            $quote  = new WP_Query($quote_args);

            if($quote->have_posts()):
                while($quote->have_posts()):
                    $quote->the_post();
                                ?>
                                <p id="testimonial">
                                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                                <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'who', true); ?></span>
                                 </p>

</div>
```

Comment: And what is wrong? You are using a deprecated parameter, and your `if` and `while` loops are not closed, but query works.

Comment: Sorry it's been along day, if I close the loop it works - which parameter is deprecated - showposts. Also is it possible to get the contents without the surrounding p tags.

Comment: The `{tax} => slug` parameter is deprecated (but still works) in favor of `tax_query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 
- you saved the post in the "quote" type 
- you actually set and save a "who" meta for those post 
- you forgot to paste the close section of the loop, 
as s_ha_dum stated, your code should work.

Like this

```
<div id="introBottom" class="group">
      <?php
      $quote_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category' => 'quote',
                'orderby' => 'rand',
                'posts_per_page' => 1
            );

            $quote  = new WP_Query($quote_args);

            if($quote->have_posts()):
                while($quote->have_posts()):
                    $quote->the_post();
                                ?>
                                <p id="testimonial">
                                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                                <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'who', true); ?></span>
                                 </p>
<?php
endwhile; 
endif;
?>
</div>
```

[posts_per_page replace showposts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)